# docker exec --workdir does not work in git-bash

Tags: windows, docker, git-bash

I'm running Docker Desktop 4.19.0 under Windows 10.

There is a container running and I can exec a command on it with `docker exec` from `git-bash`, `cmd` and Ubuntu-on-WSL2.

```
#git-bash
me@machine MINGW64 ~
$ docker exec 3eef5ce3f69d pwd
/

#cmd
C:\Users\me>docker exec 3eef5ce3f69d pwd
/

#ubuntu
frank@machine:~$ docker exec 3eef5ce3f69d pwd
/
```

so far, so good. The problem arises when I want to change the WORKDIR.

While that works on `cmd` and `ubuntu`, it fails when run from `git-bash`. But why?

```
#git-bash
me@machine MINGW64 ~
$ docker exec --workdir=/tmp 3eef5ce3f69d pwd
OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: Cwd must be an absolute path: unknown

#cmd
C:\Users\me>docker exec --workdir=/tmp 3eef5ce3f69d pwd
/tmp

#ubuntu
frank@machine:~$ docker exec --workdir=/tmp 3eef5ce3f69d pwd
/tmp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git bash does some non-standard stuff with path expansion to make things like `/bin/sh` map back to the Git bash installation directory. To disable that behavior, use a leading double slash (`//path/to/file`):

```
docker exec --workdir=//tmp 3eef5ce3f69d pwd
```

Answer (score 0):

I will add one more use case for the double slash.
If you need to use `${pwd}` in docker volumes paths on Windows with git-bash.

```
docker run -it -v "/$(pwd)":/usr/src/app -w //usr/src/ maven mvn clean package
```